# Approval in doExpressCheckout response by PayPal is equivalent to notification and guarantees transferring funds?

Tags: paypal

After receiving Approval from  doExpressCheckout response, Does it guarantee the transferring of the funds? or I must wait for approval in the notification (Can take hours). Can a notification after approval in doExpressCheckout be declined?

Answer (score 0):

Things to confirm if the payment is completed and funds are transferred.

- Make sure you use `paymentaction=sale` in DoExpressCheckout(Read about [Auth/Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/))
- In Doexpresscheckout response make sure PAYMENTINFO_n_PAYMENTSTATUS` = Completed

You can also use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) know the status of the transaction.